# Is there any react js alternative that doesn't use jsx? Maybe native html code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find something that doesn't use JSX to build. Is there any alternative other framework that will accomplish this as fast as react does?

Comment: This will get closed, but what's the point of asking "I want to use something like <x> but not <x>", you should explain why <x> isn't appropriate.

Comment: You can use react w/o jsx. `React.createElement('div', props, ...children)`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I do want something that doesnt use jsx and uses html and plain js

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: http://dodo.mikosoft.info - The Dodo as an alternative framework. Blazing fast, easy to learn, Javascript, frontend framework for reactive web pages & apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use vuejs. You make your html template and write you js code under the template.

Vuejs is also very comparable to react in speed.

[Here is a link to vuejs.](https://vuejs.org)